# How can the initial value be undefined in the onCreate() Firebase Cloud Code listener?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I do have the following cloud code function declaration:

```
export const fieldEnabledListener = functions.database.ref('devices/{deviceID}/fieldEnabled').onCreate((snap, context) => fieldEnabledCreated(snap, context));
```

Here is the implementation of the `fieldEnabledCreated` function in TypeScript:

```
async function fieldEnabledCreated(snap: DataSnapshot, context: EventContext) {

    const deviceID = (context.params as any).deviceID;

    try {
        const deviceSnap = await (<admin.database.Reference>snap.ref.parent).once("value");
        const device: Device = deviceSnap.val();

        if (device.fieldEnabled) {
            // Do stuff with the field.
        } else {
            var valueOfTheField = device.fieldEnabled
            console.log(`Value is - ${valueOfTheField}`);
        }

        return Promise.resolve();

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

The resulting logs indicate that the value is `undefined`. How can the initial value of the field be `undefined` in its onCreate() call? If it is created, shouldn't it come with a value? Just willing to know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Where does the variable `deviceSnap` come from?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Will fix that now, it was supposed to be `fieldSnap`. Thanks @ConstantinBeer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snap` will always come with the snapshot in the database that was just created.  However, that value isn't guaranteed to be around if it's queried later.  It looks like, to me, that something has deleted the parent location in the database between the time that the update happened, and the time that the function was executed (you can indeded expect some latency, triggers are not immediate).

Comment: I see! This is the most logical explanation that I can think of. Thanks for chiming in!